# Android Studio resource linking failed and quick access to the problematic files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

In old times of Android Studio, when I had compilation error and something was wrong resources I could quickly click on the error and was pointing me to the file. Now I’m getting error `com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed` but there is nothing to click that takes me quickly to the file to fix an error. Can I find these links somewhere?

[image]

Comment: post full stack trace...it is most probably due to a corrupted resource file

Answer (score 1):

You can find the issue on your project using the build report on Android Studio. You just need to switch between views:

[image]

This view will show the **gradle build logs**, and most likely will contain the resources issue.

Comment: Thanks, Andre, I could see this issues on my split view. However, I need to still manually find files from this error. I'm looking for something that will display links to problematic files like is available for normal Java / Kotlin code. Now, I'm not sure if it was available in old Android Studio or I was dreaming about it :)

Comment: @qbait Glad that this fixes your issue. Please mark this answer has it correct one so it can helper others :)

Comment: sorry, it didn't